# Solaris mounting partitions

Tags: mount, partition, solaris-10

I'm trying to mount a partition in solaris 10...

```
bash-3.00# mount /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3 /data
mount: /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3 is already mounted or /data is busy
```

As far as I know c0t0d0s3 isn't already mounted elsewhere, so what's really going on here?

From /etc/mnttab :

```
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0       /       ufs     rw,intr,largefiles,logging,xattr,onerror=panic,dev=7800001285811136
/devices        /devices        devfs   dev=4840000     1285811125
ctfs    /system/contract        ctfs    dev=48c0001     1285811125
proc    /proc   proc    dev=4880000     1285811125
mnttab  /etc/mnttab     mntfs   dev=4900001     1285811125
swap    /etc/svc/volatile       tmpfs   xattr,dev=4940001       1285811125
objfs   /system/object  objfs   dev=4980001     1285811125
sharefs /etc/dfs/sharetab       sharefs dev=49c0001     1285811125
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap1.so.1  /lib/libc.so.1  lofs    dev=780000      1285811131
fd      /dev/fd fd      rw,dev=4b40001  1285811136
swap    /tmp    tmpfs   xattr,dev=4940002       1285811137
swap    /var/run        tmpfs   xattr,dev=4940003       1285811137
-hosts  /net    autofs  nosuid,indirect,ignore,nobrowse,dev=4c00001     1285811148
auto_home       /home   autofs  indirect,ignore,nobrowse,dev=4c00002    1285811148
cordb:vold(pid530) /vol    nfs     ignore,noquota,dev=4bc0001      1285811149
```

I suspect the problem is not related to the mount point, but rather the disk slice I'm trying to mount:

```
bash-3.00# newfs -v /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3
/dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s3: Device busy
```

Comment: What's in /etc/mnttab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using:

```
fuser -c /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3
```

(or the rdsk equivalent) to see if there are any processes using that specific raw disk. Since this is Solaris 10, I have to ask does that partition contain any SVM or ZPOOL data that might be causing it to be used?

I know this was already basically suggested, but I didn't see the `-c`, so also try:

```
fuser -c /data
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running `fuser /data` to see if any process has /data as its current directory or has a file open under that directory.

Comment: Nup, it's not the mount point:

Comment: bash-3.00# fuser /data
/data:

Answer (score 0):

There is some process whose current working directory is the /data directory.
You could use the pwdx command on every running process.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a "force" option to umount.  Have you tried it?  (It has been a while since I worked with Solaris.)  I believe fuser also requires a command line option to work with a mount point.  God help ya...but, you could unlink the device file and run mknod to recreate it....what about devfsadm...that used to work in Solaris 8.  I think there is a new device manager...can't remember its name.  I can't remember the whole use...but, IIRC, there was something about using luxadm to unmount a problematic disk.  Yes, I know luxadm is/was for FC...but, something about it used to work with plain old SCSI.